# Display N lines after matching a string using Windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, append

In Linux we can easily display N lines after matching a string, such as:

> grep -A 100 "string" file1 > file2

What is the equivalent command in Windows batch scripting?

Answer (score 0):

Windows batch doesn't do much. You have to resort to .Net based PowerShell that is quite powerful.

I would like you to note that the Linux shell provides an excellent infrastructure but would be powerless without the many supporting applications such as grep that you happened to mention.

The answer to your question is with PowerShell sls command with the -Context option: see

https://superuser.com/questions/742115/powershell-equivalent-of-grep-r-l-files-with-matches.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Batch wasn't intended for such purposes, but it can be coaxed to do the job.

Here's a demonstration:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:: look for various sections

CALL q29044669s "100lines.txt" "line45" 6
ECHO ======================================
CALL q29044669s "100lines.txt" "line21" 16
ECHO ======================================
CALL q29044669s "100lines.txt" "line11" 4
ECHO ======================================

GOTO :eof
```

This merely calls the batch that actually does the job 3 times, looking for the string `line45/21/11` in the file `100lines.txt` and reproducing the 6/16/4 lines following.

`100lines.txt` is simply a test file,

```
line1
line2
```

and so on.

Here's a batch to actually do the job:

**q29044669S.bat**

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: reproduce %3 lines after finding %2 in file %1

SET "count="
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%~1") DO (
 IF DEFINED count (
  ECHO(%%a
  SET /a count+=1
  IF !count! geq %3 GOTO :EOF 
 ) ELSE (
  ECHO(%%a|FIND /i "%~2">NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET /a count=0
  REM if you want to output the line on which the target is found, remove the rem from the next line
  REM echo(%%a
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Where the `/i` on the `find` command makes the match case-insensitive.

It ensures `count` is first cleared, then applies each line of the file to `%%a` (noting that empty lines will be skipped.) When the target line is found, `count` is initialised to 0 and then the following lines are reproduced and `count` increased each time. When the limit is reached, the batch exits which ends the local environment, restoring the initial value of `count` (had it been set)

You could execute this from the command line with

```
q29044669s "100lines.txt" "line45" 6
```

but since it's a batch file, it needs to be `call`ed from within a batch as in the demo.

Note that the quotes are only strictly required if the filename/target string contains a separator (like space or comma) and may be omitted otherwise. The batch name is not important - call it what you like.

Answer (score 0):

My [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) can do this easily. JREPL.BAT is a hybrid JScript/batch utility that performs regular expression replacement on text. It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

Here is one way to do it using a bit of user supplied JScript:

```
jrepl "search" "cnt=101;$0" /j /a /jbeg "cnt=0" /jendln "if (cnt) {output.writeLine($txt); if (!--cnt) output.writeLine('--');}" /f file1 /o file2
```

The above works well because it can process any size file as long as each line is smaller than 2GB. You can add the `/I` option to make the search case insensitive, and the `/L` option treats the search as a string literal. You can add the `/X` option to allow escape sequences even if the `/L` option is used.

It can also be solved using pure regex:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "search=search"
set "before=0"
set "after=100"
call jrepl "^(?:(?:(?:.(?!%search%))*\n){0,%before%}(?:.*(?:%search%).*\n?)(?:(?:.(?!%search%))*\n?){0,%after%})+" "$0+'--'" /jmatch /m /f file1 /o file2
```

The advantage of this regex solution is it supports both leading and trailing context. The disadvantage is the entire input file must be loaded into memory, so it is limited to less than 2GB total size. Also, it does not support a literal option, so you must manually escape any regex meta-characters.

I've incorporated the regex solution into a new utility script called ShowContext.bat. All the work is done with the same call from above. Most of the code is documentation, argument parsing/validation, and error handling.

**ShowContext.bat**

```
:::
:::ShowContext.bat  <Search>  <LeadingLines>  <TrailingLines>  [/option [val]]...
:::
:::  Write the context of lines matching a regular expression search string.
:::  The default reads input from stdin and writes output to stdout
:::
:::    <Search>         The regular expression search string
:::
:::    <LeadingLines>   Number of lines written prior to a matching line
:::
:::    <TrailingLines>  Number of lines written after a matching line
:::
:::  Options:
:::
:::    /I               Case-Insensitive search
:::
:::    /X               Enable use of \q (double quote) within <Search>
:::
:::    /OFF <MinWidth>  Prefix each context with the byte offset. The offset
:::                     is zero prefixed to a minimum width of <MinWidth>.
:::                     A <MinWidth> of 0 disables the option.
:::
:::    /S  <InVar>      Read input from variable <InVar>
:::
:::    /F  <InFile>     Read input from file <InFile>
:::
:::    /O  <OutFile>    Write output to file <OutFile>.
:::                     If <OutFile> is - then overwrite <InFile>
:::
:::ShowContext  /?      Prints this documentation
:::
::::
::::This script requires JREPL.BAT to function.
::::JREPL.BAT is available at http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044
::::
::::JREPL.BAT must be in one of the following locations:
::::  - the current directory
::::  - the same folder as this script
::::  - any of the folders within PATH
::::

@echo off
setlocal

:: Locate JREPL.BAT
if exist "jrepl.bat" (
  set "jrepl=jrepl.bat"
) else if exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" (
  set "jrepl=%~dp0jrepl.bat"
) else for %%F in (jrepl.bat) do set "jrepl=%%~$path:F"
if not defined jrepl (
  for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr "^::::" "%~f0"') do echo(%%A
  exit /b 2
)>&2

:: Show help
if "%~1" == "/?" if "%~2" equ "" (
  for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr "^:::$ ^:::[^:]" "%~f0"') do echo(%%A
  exit /b 0
)

:: Load required arguments
set "search=%~1"
if not defined search goto :error
set /a "before=%~2, after=%~3" || goto :error
shift /1
shift /1
shift /1

:: Clear ERRORLEVEL
(call )

:: Do the work via JREPL.BAT
call "%jrepl%" "^(?:(?:(?:.(?!%search%))*\n){0,%before%}(?:.*(?:%search%).*\n?)(?:(?:.(?!%search%))*\n?){0,%after%})+" "$0+'--'" /jmatch /m %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8
if errorlevel 2 goto :error
exit /b %errorlevel%

:error
>&2 echo(
>&2 echo ERROR: Invalid or Insufficient arguments. Use ShowContext /? to see usage.
exit /b 2
```

Using the above, your solution becomes:

```
ShowContext "search" 0 100 /f file1 /o file2
```